# Change #NA To 0

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

How can I change the #NA to 0 in this function.  As is, it's returning #NA, which is correct.  But I want it to return 0 instead.

```
=VLOOKUP(R11,Lookup!$Z$2:$AB$332,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is applied with its fourth parameter `0` (FALSE):

> If an exact match is not found, the error value #N/A is returned.

But this can be detected (trapped) within a formula and an alternative result shown instead of `#N/A`. This alternative could be almost anything but OP has chose `0` so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R11,Lookup!$Z$2:$AB$332,2,0),0)
```

In early versions of Excel IFERROR is not available but, though longer, an alternative is:

```
 =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(R11,lookup!$Z$2:$AB$332,2,0)),0,VLOOKUP(R11,lookup!$Z$2:$AB$332,2,0))
```